# Align items in horizontal ListView.builder - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, alignment

I have this code :

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _data,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(child: CustomLoadingAnimation());
      } else {
        var data = snapshot.data;
        return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: primaryFlashColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              height: 14.h,
              width: 100.w,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ThreadIcon(
                          title: data[index]['title'],
                          url: data[index]['pic']);
                    }),
              ),
            );
      }
    })
```

And this preview :

[image: preview]

As you can see, the first item has his title only in 1 line, so the image is lower than the others.

Any idea that can help to fix this ?

**EDIT : Here is my ThreadIcon widget : as you can see, there is 2 maxLine. But when title is only on 1 line, items are not aligned horizontally**

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 2, color: customWhite),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
            child: Image.network(
              url.toString(),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 1.h,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 45,
        child: Text(
          title.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            fontSize: 11,
          ),
          maxLines: 2,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: ig you can use `maxLine:1` on your `Text` widget

Comment: It is a solution but some titles need 2 lines as you can see on the preview. So I need to keep the maxLine : 2.

Comment: It will be easier if you could include simple version that will reproduce the same error, also you can include `ThreadIcon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I needed to put a fixed height in my ThreadIcon widget :

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 2, color: customWhite),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
            child: Image.network(
              url.toString(),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 1.h,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 45,
        height: 30, // here add fixed height
        child: Text(
          title.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            fontSize: 11,
          ),
          maxLines: 2,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row` to align items with equal space on sides (if you're certain about the length of the items). The `ListView` will occupy the available space and it'll keep adding the items one after another.

Comment: The problem is the length is variable. And the problem is not about sides, but the first item is lower than other (because title is only 1 line)